# Can't remove index.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1

I've just installed a fresh version of Magento 2.4.3-p1.

I can access my website like domain.com

Once I'm on the Magento homepage, all other links contain .index.php in the url, such as:
https://domaine.com/index.php/search/term/popular/

Or even:
https://domain.com/index.php/ if I click on the logo.

How can I remove this index.php ?

In Configuration > Web, it is set like this:
[image]

And:

[image]

Cache was cleared, index refreshed too.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things.

```
1   Go To Stores > Configuration > Web
2   expand the Search Engine Optimization section
3   set Use Web Server Rewrites to “Yes.”
4   When complete, tap Save Config
```

After above things, run the following command from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Then try to open the website without index.php.

Answer (score 0):

OK solved.

Had to restart Varnish !

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php in the frontend URLs performing the following steps in Magento's admin section go to :

System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations, select YES.

Edit the /installdir/.htaccess and uncomment the line:

RewriteBase /magento/

In my case the subdirectory Magento is in is called magento, so change it to your subdirectory path if it is different.

I hope this will solve your problem